# Affine transformation in C

Tags: math

I hope I can post my question here (maybe on [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?)

I have an array of coordinates

```
double coordinates[MAX_COORD][2]
```

And an array of 6 coordinates containing the first 3 coordinates (coordinates[0][0]...)

```
double points[6][2]
```

and other 3 coordinates inserted by the user.

How can I transform the six coordinates into a function to transform all coordinates?

```
void affineTrasformation(double coord[MAX_COORD][2], const double points[6][2])
```

The affine transformation formula is:

```
X = a*x + b*y + c
Y = d*x + e*y + f
```

The problem is obtaining the 6 variables (a, b, c, d, e, f) from my 6 points.

Thanks

Comment: Just an hint: we have here a product of matrices...

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you have three original points `(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)` and three transformed points `(X1,Y1), (X2,Y2), (X3,Y3)`.  Using your transformation formula we get 6 equations:

```
X1 = a*x1 + b*y1 + c
Y1 = d*x1 + e*y1 + f
X2 = a*x2 + b*y2 + c
Y2 = d*x2 + e*y2 + f
X3 = a*x3 + b*y3 + c
Y3 = d*x3 + e*y3 + f
```

This is a linear equation system for your 6 unknown coefficients `a,b,c,d,e,f`.  Such a system of 6 equations and 6 unknowns can be solved by using standard methods from linear algebra, e.g. [LAPACK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapack) or [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/).

This works if, and only if, the three original points are not on a straight line.